# How to check whether a file was updated in HDFS using Java?

Tags: java, hdfs

I need to create a process in order to verify if files into a specified directory was updated in HDFS. This event will trigger an action and should run indefinitely.

I tried using `getAccessTime` and `getModificationTime`, but without success. Is there some requirement to do that using those methods or another viable approach without keeping a hash for each file?

Comment: Can you please provide more detail as to what went wrong with `getModificationTime`? Any error messages, what you expected, what you saw, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The value of lastModified in the java.io.File class will update whenever a file changes regardless of file system.  There are several good file monitoring APIs, I would suggest using FileAlterationMonitor in Apache commons.

```
File f = new File("F:\\program.txt"); 

System.out.println("Last modified: "
                       + f.lastModified());
```